# What is this piece of children's playground apparatus called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I want to call this a "roundabout". But, in Britain anyway, a "roundabout" is much larger with bars on it to sit on ([as demonstrated by a Google images search for "playground roundabout"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=919&q=playground%20roundabout&oq=playground%20roundabout&gs_l=img.3..0l2j0i5j0i24l4j0i5i24l2.1870.4790.0.4925.21.17.0.4.4.0.75.923.17.17.0...0.0...1ac.l4aW1RMSRJ0)).

They're a fairly new addition to playgrounds, I think. They certainly didn't exist when I was a kid.

But what are they actually called?

[image]

Comment: That does remind me of a top: "a child's toy that spins on a point when it is turned round very quickly by hand or by a string"

Comment: It looks like a variation on a teacup.

Comment: I hadn't ever seen that in my country. I'm wondering if there is a coaxial rotor under the ground which can move it dinamically.

Comment: @Carlo No, it's all manual. (We're in recession over here!)

Comment: A *Vomit Inducer 3000* maybe?

Comment: In the US we call the bigger version you mentioned a "merry-go-round".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you get the picture from [here](http://raypps.co.uk/inclusive-spinning-dish.html)?

It's called an "Inclusive Spinning Dish" or a "Dish Roundabout"

Comment: I just did image searches till I found one. Looks like the same one though.

Comment: I can just imagine five-year-olds at recess, "Let's go play on the inclusive spinning dish!"

Comment: @root45 Well, the equipment does *include* a spinning dish ... I see no problem with calling swings "inclusive damped oscillatory pendulum"

Answer (score 7):

I would probably call it a "cup" or "spinning cup", and I most people would understand, if they had seen it.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see any reason to call it anything different from the manufacturers (linked elsewhere here) who describe it as a ***Spinning Dish***. The additional attribute of 'inclusive' seems to be more of an advertising adjective.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a spring rider -- the thing on top, in that it is a dish is almost incidental to the underlying type of ride.

Comment: Most spring riders don't spin.

Comment: I don't see how that spins -- it seems to bend at all angles. Is there something in this which states that it spins independently of the bendability? on a spring rider, you can effectively spn by bending in a circular motion. Looking at the website, i see that they claim it spins on an axis, but don't claim any central spring so what is the source of the "give" evidenced in the photo.

Comment: if it simply spins, then it is a form of a carousel, raised a bit http://www.playground-usa.com/SpringRider/big/mpl001b.jpg

Comment: If you believe the advertising, it rocks *and* spins. So it's a spring rider *and* roundabout. [Here's another brand](http://www.smp.co.uk/product/b1ed69de-62ca-e011-aa59-0050569301ea/).

Comment: @PeterShor: I thought it was a spring rider as well, but those who have actually let their kids play on the thing insist that it's primarily a spinning apparatus, even if it does rock a little bit.  Maybe we need to organize a field trip where we can all convene and discuss. I'd love to spin it around with Barrie England in there! :^)

Answer (score -2):

a carousel. As kids we used to call it a puke-o-matic :) but I would be unable to say how widely used that term is.

...

A dictionary lookup later: It may also be called a roundabout as you yourself suggest.

Comment: Aren't carousels those large merry-go-rounds with horses to sit on?

Comment: Carousel is a great word, but it has such a variety of meanings. I think you are both right.

Comment: I think, if you said it, people would be likely to misunderstand. I don't see one on here: https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=10&hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1680&bih=919&q=carousel&oq=carousel&gs_l=img.12...0.0.0.1287.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.ufQIzFbRM6Y

Comment: @Urbycoz Yes, that is what I was referring to ...

Comment: indeed it is also called a merry-go-round. If you wish to distinguish you will have to use context to do so.

Comment: When used for playground equipment, carousel, merry-go-round and roundabout are all [synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundabout_%28play%29). The OP wants a different word that is more specific to this .